# why isn't my code reacting to this if statement (Global Variables)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game where I have buttons on the canvas connected to public 'GameVar's and when the forward one is pressed or the W button is pressed, I want it to change the x of the 'runaxis' vector2 and display "forward" on a public string to show it.

I've already tried adding things like ' == true' etc, but none of it seems to work

```
public class ClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string GoingFB;

    void Update()
    {
        if (GameVar.ForwardArrow || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            FPS.runAxis.x = 2f;
            GoingFB = "Forward"; 
        }

        if (GameVar.BackArrow || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            FPS.runAxis.x = -2f;
            GoingFB = "Backward";
        }

        if (GameVar.ForwardArrow == GameVar.BackArrow || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            FPS.runAxis.x = 0f;
            GoingFB = "Null";
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expect it to say "forward" in the inspector when I press the forward arrow. I have tested the arrows, and they do change the GameVar.

Comment: What did you observe when you set a breakpoint on the `if` statement and then stepped through the code one line at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not that code not reaching if statement. Problem is that expression in your last if statement is always true so `GoingFB` value is always set to `null` at the end of `Update` method which is called on every frame update. expression in your last if will be only `false` if either both S and BackArrow is pressed, or both W and FormardArrow is pressed. For example if only W is pressed: `GameVar.ForwardArrow == GameVar.BackArrow` this expression will be `true` since in this case both `GameVar.ForwardArrow`and `GameVar.BackArrow`is false. so after setting string value to "Forward" in first if statement, it will be immediately reset to "Null" after in 3rd if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
    if (GameVar.BackArrow || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == True))
```

You should use an if else statement as Giorgi mentioned.